# Passing a variable within db_id()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure why the variable is treated differently when passed within a sub-query within the "if statement" but works fine when executed independently.

The successful one

```
select db_id(( Select name from sys.databases where database_id > 4))
```

Result:

```
DBSIZE
--------
5
```

Where it returns Null:

```
Declare @dbcount int;

set @dbcount = (Select  count(*) from sys.databases where database_id > 4);

If  @dbcount = 1

Begin

select usedspace as 'DBSize'  
from       
(   
SELECT (s.size * CONVERT(float,8))/1024 AS [Size],
(CAST(CASE s.type WHEN 2 THEN 0 ELSE CAST(FILEPROPERTY(s.name, 'SpaceUsed') AS float)* CONVERT(float,8) END AS float))/1024 AS [UsedSpace],
s.file_id AS [ID]
FROM
sys.filegroups AS g 
INNER JOIN sys.master_files AS s ON ((s.type = 2 or s.type = 0) and s.database_id = db_id((Select name from sys.databases where database_id > 4)) and (s.drop_lsn IS NULL)) AND (s.data_space_id=g.data_space_id)
) DBFileSizeInfo 

End

else

Print 'The instance has more than 1 database'
```

Result:

```
DBSize
---------
NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FILEPROPERTY` call is returning null, because:

> FILEPROPERTY (Transact-SQL)
>
> Returns the specified file name property value when a file name in the current database and a property name are specified. **Returns NULL for files that are not in the current database.**

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188401.aspx

You need to `use` the database before calling `FILEPROPERTY`, so you will need to build some dynamic SQL, unfortunately.

Comment: I kinda was walking toward that direction.Thanks for your help